# Copy last updated row from Sheet1 to Sheet2

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
data.forEach(function(f) {
    if (~f.indexOf(searchtext)) {
      ar.push(f);
    }
  });
  return ar;
}





function isUpdated(data) {
  var arrayLength = data.length;
  var updated = false;
  var oldData = search(data[1]);
  
  for (var i = 1; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    if(oldData[0][i] != data[i]){
      updated = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  
  
 
  
  return updated;
}

function update(data){
  data = JSON.parse(data)
  const tag = data[1].toString().trim().toUpperCase()
  const ws = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SS_ID).getSheetByName(SN_DATA)
  const values = ws.getDataRange().getValues()
  const index = values.findIndex(v => v[1].toString().trim().toUpperCase() === tag)

  


  if (index === -1) return false
  ws.getRange(index + 1, 1, 1, data.length).setValues([data])

  return true
}
```

Hello expert I'm able to write a code to search and update using Web App. google Sheet Sheet1 can anyone help ,e how to copy my last edited/updated rows to sheet2? I want to add row function every time the sheet1 has been updated the updated column will logs to sheet2? code has been provide above

Comment: If your question is about Google Sheets, why did you tag it as Excel instead? There is a tag for Google Sheets available. Please use only tags that are actually applicable to your post. Tags have relevance and meaning here. Thanks.

Comment: @TwistedMind Please read [how-to-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @TwistedMind Introduce the problem before showing the code. This will help get more responses